# Proving that a system of polynomial matrix equations over $\mathbb{F_2}$ has no solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I am working on a problem involving nilpotent matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$ and I was able to reduce it to proving that the system
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      A^2+ BC+ BCA+ ABC+A = I_4 \\
      AB+ABD+BCB = 0 \\
      CA+DCA+CBC = 0 \\
      DCB+CBD = I_4 \\
      A^3+BCA+ABC+BDC=0 \\
      A^2B+BCB+ABD+BD^2=0 \\
      CA^2+DCA+CBC+D^2C=0 \\
      CAB+DCB+CBD+D^3=0
    \end{cases}\,,
\end{equation}
has no solution, where $A, B, C, D$ are $4 \times 4$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2.$
The first four equations were obtained by plugging-in matrices to some polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2$ while the other four came from the condition that
$$\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
A & B \\
\hline
C & D
\end{array}
\right]^3 = 0.$$

Any advice on how to prove this? Any help would be appreciated.

The original problem is if
$$M=\begin{bmatrix} N & 0 \\ 0 & N \end{bmatrix}, \mbox{ where } N=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
then $M$ cannot be written as a sum $X+Y$ such that $X^3=0$ and $Y^2=Y.$ Here  $M, X, Y$ are matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Write $X=[x_{i,j}], Y=[y_{i,j}]$.
For each $(i,j)$, $i,j \in \{1, \ldots, 8\}$, $x_{i,j}$ and $y_{i,j}$ satisfies the following equations:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^8\sum_{l=1}^8 x_{i,k}x_{k,l}x_{l,j}=0\\
      \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^8 y_{i,k}y_{k,j}=y_{i,j}\\ 
      x_{i,j}+y_{i,j}=m_{i,j} \\
      x_{i,j}^2= x_{i,j} \\
      y_{i,j}^2= y_{i,j}
    \end{cases}\,,
\end{equation}

So we want to show that this system has no solution via Groebner basis and implement it using Maple. I have zero background in Maple so I need help with the code. So what I've researched is we start with

```
with(Groebner);
```

and define matrix $M$:

```
M:=[[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]];
```

Define the following polynomials for all $(i,j)$:

```
f_{i,j}= \sum_{k=1}^8\sum_{l=1}^8 x_{i,k}x_{k,l}x_{l,j};
g_{i,j}= \sum_{k=1}^8 y_{i,k}y_{k,j}-y_{i,j};
h_{i,j}=x_{i,j}+y_{i,j}-M[i,j];
q_{i,j}=x_{i,j}^2-x_{i,j};
s_{i,j}=y_{i,j}^2-y_{i,j};
```

and we let for all $(i,j)$

```
B:=[f_{i,j},g_{i,j},h_{i,j},q_{i,j},s_{i,j}];
```

and call

```
G:=Groebner[Basis](B, plex(x_{i,j},y_{i,j}), characteristic=2);
```

We expect that the output is

```
G:=[1]
```

Is this correct? Also, how do I typeset the summations in Maple, and how do I typeset the polynomials so that I don't have to manually type for all 64 pairs $(i,j)$? Thank you so much.

Comment: What is the original problem? Given the information you've provided, my intuition is that this formulation (via systems of equations of matrices) is quite possibly much harder to directly approach than the original problem.

Comment: I added the original question

Comment: It’s easy to prove this if, additionally, $X$ and $Y$ commute: then since $X$ is nilpotent, the eigenvalues of $X+Y$ are just the eigenvalues of $Y$, which are $0$ or $1$. However, the eigenvalues of $M$ are the eigenvalues of $N$, which are roots of the polynomial $x^4+x^3+1$ (irreducible over $\mathbb F_2$).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek where did you use the fact that the index of nilpotency of X is 3? Because if the index of nilpotency of X is 4, then the statement will actually be false

Comment: I didn't, and it holds for any nilpotent matrix $X$. But to repeat, the argument only applies if $X$ and $Y$ commute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can solve quickly this problem using the basis Grobner theory.

Put $X=[x_{i,j}],Y=[y_{i,j}]$.

We consider -over a field of characteristic $2$- the algebraic system in the $128$ unknowns $x_{i,j},y_{i,j}$ constituted by the equations $M=X+Y,X^3=0,Y^2=Y$ -entrywise- and $x_{i,j}^2=x_{i,j},y_{i,j}^2=y_{i,j}$.

With the help of the FGb library of Maple, we obtain (in 36") that there are no solutions.

$\textbf{Answer to the OP.}$ The maple command "with(Groebner)" is not very efficient; prefer the command  "with(FGb)". You need to load the patch here (available only on LINUX)

http://www.mathemagix.org/www/mfgb/doc/html/install_fgb.en.html

Otherwise use "with(Groebner) but it may be a long way.

You can also use "Sage" very powerful but not very practical to use.
Here is the program I used.

restart:

with(LinearAlgebra):

n := 8:

N := Matrix([[0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1]]):

M := DiagonalMatrix([N, N]):

X := Matrix(8, symbol = x):

Y := Matrix(8, symbol = y):

C := M-X-Y: E := X^3: P := Y^2-Y:

K := NULL:

for i to n do

for j to n do

K := K, x[i, j], y[i, j] end do end do:

K := [K]:

F := NULL:

for i to n do

for j to n do

F := F, C[i, j], E[i, j], P[i, j], x[i, j]^2-x[i, j], y[i, j]^2-y[i, j] end do end do:

F := [F]:

with(FGb):

t := time():

solu := fgb_gbasis(F, 2, K, [], {"index" = 10^7, "verb" = 3});

nops(solu):

t3 := time()-t:

Comment: Okay, I'll try this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello, I added my attempt in the question. I need help with the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There are only $2^{16}$ possible $4 \times 4$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$.  That means that by examining $2^{32}$ possibilities, you can exhaust $A$ and $B$.  Once $A$ and $B$ are known, your first equation becomes linear, so it's straightforward to solve for $C$.  Given $A, B$ and $C$, your second equation now becomes linear and you can solve for $D$.

You will either find a solution or prove that none exists.  I'd imagine that a reasonably efficient program should be able to try all the possibilities in a few seconds.

Comment: I agree that brute force will be successful, but "a few seconds" is optimistic.  The equations for C and D are linear but not always nonsingular, so the number of subcases could be a lot larger than $2^{32}$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I already tried to brute force the original problem, however the code runs really slow (although maybe my code is inefficient)

Comment: Ah, that's an excellent point, @BrendanMcKay -- I guess singular matrices might torpedo us, absent more cleverness.  The matrices do seem like they're 4x4, though, right?